# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot API that I want to call a stored procedure, but I am getting internal server error. The stored procedure on its own is working fine when I call it through mssql. I have tried multiple ways of calling it, but I am not successful.

looking at the query generated it is adding second argument `{call validateCustomer(?,?)}`

Below is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, BigInteger> {
    @Procedure(procedureName = "VALIDATECUSTOMER", outputParameterName = "customer")
    String validateCustomer(@Param("customer") String customer);
}
```

Below is the Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[VALIDATECUSTOMER]
    @customer nvarchar(max) out
as
    set @customer=@customer
    select @customer as customer
```

Detailed error

```
2022-11-05 10:05:38.030  INFO 28852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9800 (http) with context path ''
2022-11-05 10:05:38.136  INFO 28852 --- [  restartedMain] mw.nbs.ekyc.EkycApplication              : Started EkycApplication in 5.428 seconds (JVM running for 6.798)
2022-11-05 10:05:50.290  INFO 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-05 10:05:50.292  INFO 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-05 10:05:50.293  INFO 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-11-05 10:05:50.586  WARN 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2022-11-05 10:05:50.586 ERROR 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The value is not set for the parameter number 2.
2022-11-05 10:05:50.613 ERROR 28852 --- [nio-9800-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildParamTypeDefinitions(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:438) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildPreparedStrings(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:391) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:569) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:537) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7730) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3786) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:515) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:632) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:615) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:315) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

Comment: Can you add  
`spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see executed query before exception was thrown?

Comment: Its really shows two arguments but I only set one argument

Answer (score 0):

I cahnged the way of calling procedure to

```
@Query(value = "{ CALL validateCustomer(:customer) }", nativeQuery = true)
```

from

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "validateCustomer", outputParameterName = "customer")
```